# Как вызвать метод Активити из фрагмента? Xamarin android

Tags: android, android-fragment, xamarin

Есть некий метод в MainActivity.cs...назовем его Test(). И есть фрагмент. в котором описана некая кнопка

```
button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1); 
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //вызов метода Test()           
    }
```

Каким образом реализовать вызов этого метода?

PS xamarin android

Answer (score 4):

Мне никто не помог, и пришлось понять самостоятельно. Чтобы вызвать метод Активити из фрагмента нужно сделать так в коде фрагмента: `MainActivty ma = (MainActivity)this.Activity;`, а потом обращаться к любому методу через `ma.test();` Иначе были проблемы или с передачей данных или с типом метода...

Answer (score 1):

Вот так будет правильнее:

if (getActivity() != null)
{
  MainActivity ma = (MainActivity ) getActivity();
  ma.test();
}

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `this.MainActivity.Test()`.

Comment: В таком варианте, он говорит, что метода такого просто не существует. Хотя он есть.